# Parse and TryParse

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I wanted to know what others are doing with parse/try parse for decimals as an example.
In PHP, I would write a method called GetValueOrDefault(value, default) that takes in two parameters - the first parameter is a string or value you'd LIKE to try to parse as an integer or decimal, and the second parameter is the default should that fail.

I want something like this in .net but I'm seeing this:

```
  decimal salary = 0.0; //initialize salary
  if (!Decimal.TryParse(myStringValue, out salary))
      salary = 0;
```

So for me, the "Tryparse" boolean return type is not necessary for me - i'm not taking any special action, and don't care. All I want is "If there is a conversion fail, then default back to what I initialized the value to, otherwise don't do anything."

Also, I don't want to do a Parse, as my understanding is that will throw an exception. I don't need to try..catch because i've already initialized the variable (What more should I do in the catch? I don't need to log anywhere).

Should I really write an extension method or helper utility method to do the above? I feel like there is an easy solution to this that i'm clearly missing.

Thanks all!

Comment: Yes, if you want to have a method that does something different from the existing methods you should write your own method.  Clearly implementing the method you want is easy enough thanks to the `TryParse` methods.

Comment: If your default value is always 0, you don't need to write another method.  If `TryParse()` fails to parse your string, it sets the value of the number to 0.

Comment: I would consider avoiding naming your method `GetValueOrDefault()` - `Nullable<T>` types already have that method hanging off of them.  Why not `TryParseOrDefault()`?

Comment: @GoldenDragon is right.  For your scenario (if you don't need to know if it failed or not), removing the `if` gives you the same result

Comment: Out parameters don't have to be initialized, so you could use this:

  decimal salary;
  if (!Decimal.TryParse(myStringValue, out salary))
      salary = 0.0;

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care whether or not it parsed, there's no real need to wrap it in an `if`.  If it fails, however, your `salary` reference parameter will be zero.  So in a situation where you've initialized `salary` to something besides zero, you should care if it parsed.

Comment: If you don't check the return value then you can't tell the difference between an unparsed value and a value that happened to be parsed to zero.  This is *only* an option if the desired default value is zero, which is not the case for this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var salary = Decimal.TryParse(myStringValue, out var value) ? value : 0;
```

Answer (score -2):

I always use an extension method, very similar to what usr suggested, with a slight variance:

```
public static decimal GetDecimalOrDefault(this string value, decimal defaultDecimal)
{
    try 
    {
        return Convert.ToDecimal(value);
    }
    catch(exception ex)
    {
        return defaultDecimal;
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
decimal finalValue = 0.0;
string myStringValue = "123.456";
finalValue = myStringValue.GetDecimalOrDefault(finalValue);
```

Comment: Exceptions should not be used for control flow.

Comment: @Servy What's the reasoning behind that? I feel my solution satisfies the requirements of the question, but unless there's something performance-impacting about it, I don't think it's necessarily a wrong answer.

Comment: There's a huge performance impact on every exception, That's a bad solution